# Make qt form click through-able on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm trying to make a program that use image as form and click through able. Any idea how to make QT form click through-able? Like we set window long on windows to `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`.

I also tried `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents`. But it does not work.

Comment: really looking for something similar.. will stay tuned to your question as it might solve my problem as well..